# Spring MVC RestController test failed to find valid mapping

Tags: java, spring-test, spring-restcontroller, spring-test-mvc, spring-mvc-test

I failed to test RestController method with path variable

```
INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/my/{env}] onto handler 'myController'
INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/my/{env}.*] onto handler 'myController'
INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/my/{env}/] onto handler 'myController'
INFO org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet '': initialization completed in 205 ms
WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/my/dev/auth] in DispatcherServlet with name ''
```

My Test

```
@ContextConfiguration( classes = {Config.class, MyController.class})
@ActiveProfiles(profiles= {"dev"})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MyControllerTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAuth() throws Exception {
        MockHttpSession httpSession =  new MockHttpSession(wac.getServletContext(), UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder mockHttpServletRequestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
        .post("/my/dev/auth").content("<XML></XML>")
        .session(httpSession)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
         MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(mockHttpServletRequestBuilder)
                  .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                  .andReturn();
```

My Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/my/{env}")
public class MyController {

@PostMapping(value = "auth", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Response> authenticate(
            @PathVariable("env") String gameEnvironment, @RequestBody String xml,
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
```

**EDIT**

Removing path variable result in similar results

```
[main] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/my] onto handler 'myController'
[main] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/my.*] onto handler 'myController'
[main] INFO org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/my/] onto handler 'myController'
[main] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/my/auth] in DispatcherServlet with name ''
```

Comment: Have you tried `@RequestMapping("/my")` and `@postMapping(value="{env}/auth" ...)` instead?

Comment: @morgano yes, actually it doesn't work either, see my edit

Comment: `@RestControllers `requires more config to work in SpringTest (for some reasons) than `@Controllers ` I even had to manually create `MockMVC` in `@Before` If I rememver correctly I had to create application context and use ot to get mock mvc.

Comment: @Antoniossss added the `@Before` method to initialize MockMVC

Comment: You are not using `mockMvc` in code provided. Try to set `@Autowired` over mockMvc property and remove it from setup(). In test method  do `mockMvc.perform(post("/my/{env}/{auth}", "dev").sessionAttrs(httpSession).with("<XML></XML>"))`

Comment: @alex I added code in my test uses `mockMvc.perform` method, It seems `sessionAttrs` can't get `MockHttpSession`, also I have problem with *with*, do you mean using `post` method as in *MockMvcRequestBuilders.post*?

Comment: yes `import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;`
try `session` instead of `sessionAttrs`
check https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.html it has `with(RequestPostProcessor postProcessor)`

Comment: should be `mockMvc.perform(post("/my/{env}/auth", "dev")`

Comment: What does your `Config` class look like?

Comment: @SamBrannen `@Configuration`, but I have another configuration with `@ConditionalOnBean` adding `@EnableWebMvc`

Comment: And the latter is picked up via component scanning, or...?

Comment: @SamBrannen via component scanning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test was missing classes for full loading of relevant configuration

```
@ContextConfiguration( classes = {Config.class, MyController.class
    ,OtherConfig.class})
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works with JUnit 4.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { Config.class, MyController.class })
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@WebAppConfiguration("classpath:META-INF/web-resources")
public class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAuth() throws Exception {
        MockHttpSession httpSession = new MockHttpSession(wac.getServletContext(), UUID.randomUUID().toString());

        this.mockMvc.perform(
                post("/my/dev/auth")
                    .content("<XML></XML>")
                    .session(httpSession)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
class Config {
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/my/{env}")
class MyController {

    @PostMapping(path = "auth", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public String authenticate(@PathVariable("env") String env, @RequestBody String xml,
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

And the following works with TestNG.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { Config.class, MyController.class })
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@WebAppConfiguration("classpath:META-INF/web-resources")
public class MyControllerTestNG extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAuth() throws Exception {
        MockHttpSession httpSession = new MockHttpSession(wac.getServletContext(), UUID.randomUUID().toString());

        this.mockMvc.perform(
                post("/my/dev/auth")
                    .content("<XML></XML>")
                    .session(httpSession)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```